# Python Unit Testing - Mock Patch at Runtime?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, magicmock

I am writing unit tests in python.

My code uses `redis` frequently and I want to mock this. I'd like to do this globally and not worry about mocking it in each test, but I don't think this is possible using the `@patch` decorator.

Example of working test-

```
class ExamplesTests(AbstractTestCase, unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('main.redis')
    def test_the_thing(self, redis: MagicMock):
        redis.set = self._my_mock_set # method that sets a dict val
        redis.get = self._my_mock_get # method that gets a dict val

        result = main.do_the_thing()

        self.assertTrue(result)
```

I don't actually need what's in the mock cache, i'm just trying to prevent the need to cleanup the actual redis cache that's being used by other processes. I tried doing this in the `setUp`-

```
class AbstractTestCase(ABC):

    @patch('main.redis')
    def setUp(self, redis: MagicMock):
        redis.set = self._my_mock_set # method that sets a dict val
        redis.get = self._my_mock_get # method that gets a dict val
```

> Error: setUp() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Instead of patching every test, is it possible to use setup without the decorator? Something like this?-

```
class AbstractTestCase(ABC):

    def setUp(self):
        redis = patch('main.redis')
        redis.set = self._my_mock_set # method that sets a dict val
        redis.get = self._my_mock_get # method that gets a dict val
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed create the patch like that, but you then need to explicitly enable it as well. You'll want to stop the patch as well after the test completes.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.redis = redis = patch('main.redis')
    redis.set = ...
    redis.get = ...
    redis.start()
    self.addCleanup(redis.stop)
```